# Firebase and Google Play Game Services Won't Merge in Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I added the latest Firebase SDK Messaging package to my project with already well functioning GPGS. First it was possible to build the app with seemingly no issues involved but I found out GPGS stopped functioning giving me exception during initialization.

Hence I reinstalled it all. I tried to force resolve using Play Services Resolver and ended up with even more fatal problem.

Resolver gives me this error:

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.0


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey4:<>m__1(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

and warning

```
Some conflicting dependencies were found.
The following dependency versions were modified:
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive-license:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive-license:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby-license:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-license:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-license:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:17.0.0
com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1 --> com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.0.4 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.0.0 --> com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 --> com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:17.0.0

UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: Which unity version are you using?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Unity, but what configuration are you using to try and specify the version of dependencies to resolve? E.g. com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive has a latest version of 15.0.1 (as per maven.google.com) so it can't be resolved.